# Create an array of items with Parse

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, parse-platform

I am able to store individual item into parse, where for instance a new column name ActivityName would be created with the activity name that the user have selected upon a button click, and when a user select a different activity the activityname under ActivityName would be changed. However, I do not want it to change, rather I want it to be added to the column of ActivityName, where you would have (activity1, activity2, activityn).

Below is the code I have used to store the individual activity name that gets replaced every time an activity is clicked.

```
 @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ParseUser currentUser = ParseUser.getCurrentUser();

           // Create the class and the columns
            currentUser.saveInBackground();

            currentUser.put("ActivityName", list_item_name); 
            currentUser.put("ActivityPrice", list_item_price);
            currentUser.put("ActivityPurchasePriceCode", list_item_purchase_code);
            currentUser.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {
                @Override
                public void done(ParseException e) {
                    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);

                    if (e == null) {
                        // Success!
                        Intent intent = new Intent(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this, usermatch.class);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                    else {
                        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.this);
                        builder.setMessage(e.getMessage())
                            .setTitle(R.string.signup_error_title)
                            .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.ok, null);
                        AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
                        dialog.show();
                    }
               }
           });

        }
    });
```

I have tried using the following

```
currentUser.add("ActivityName", list_item_name); 
            currentUser.add("ActivityPrice", list_item_price);
            currentUser.add("ActivityPurchasePriceCode", list_item_purchase_code);
```

but that have not been so successful, and below is the log cat message:

```
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202): Process: com.dooba.beta, PID: 4202
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Operation is invalid after previous operation.
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at com.parse.ParseAddOperation.apply(ParseAddOperation.java:75)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at com.parse.ParseObject.performOperation(ParseObject.java:2660)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at com.parse.ParseObject.addAll(ParseObject.java:2748)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at com.parse.ParseObject.add(ParseObject.java:2734)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at com.dooba.beta.CasualEventsSingleItemActivity$2.onClick(CasualEventsSingleItemActivity.java:119)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-18 19:24:49.728: E/AndroidRuntime(4202):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

If you need any clarification, let me know.
Thanks in advance

Comment: have you tried declaring ActivityName as array in parse Data Browser ?

Comment: thanks for your prompt response.  The ActivityName was not declared as an array, would there be a way to change that without creating a new column, and in if could you kindly assist me with that

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way to do that , i can suggest you to drop that column and copy data to the new column you can create , it's the best you can solve this

Comment: Thanks for your response, and this has somehow solved my problem. I have a quick question along that line. How I would limit an array to 3 item? Where you could have (a1, a2, a3), and when a 4th item is added it would be (a4, a2, a3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to declare a column as an array type and maybe copy the data from it , as for adding array to the beginning of the array , it is not possible to do that in with parse .

Comment: would it be at least possible to limit the size of an array with Parse?

Comment: I am afraid no , it is limited by default to 500 item and 128KB per item which makes it impossible for you to define the size by yourself .

Comment: Thanks for your response. So what could be an alternative solution in your opinion?

Comment: I believe that you can put your data in json object , this will make able to both place data in position you want and limit the json object ,

Comment: but then the json object would have work directly with parse, and I would have to somehow related it. Like for instance it searches the current user at parse and returns x activity.

Comment: yes, that's true  indeed , what i meant is storing a string in JSON format in that column , just a JSON array containing your data .

Comment: Thank you. Could you elaborate more on the process of achieving that through parse?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61528/discussion-between-ail-and-user3907211).

Comment: Good to see that I am in the right direction. I receive the following error for the following line jArray.put(ActivityName, list_item_name)); 
ActivityName cannot be resolved to a variable. I tried rewording it as such jArray.put("ActivityName", list_item_name)); 
but recieved the following error The method put(int, boolean) in the type JSONArray is not applicable for the arguments (String, String). How would I set the limit to 3 with the JSON data. thank you