# Array operations sometimes throws 'Operation is invalid after previous operation'

Tags: android, parse-platform

In one of my parse subclasses I have a method like this:

```
public void updateCheckpoint(String checkpoint, boolean checked) {
    if (checked) {
        addUnique(checkedCheckpoints, checkpoint);
    } else {
        removeAll(checkedCheckpoints, Arrays.asList(checkpoint));
    }
}
```

This update is immediately followed by a pinning to the local datastore.

Even when adding a ProgressDialog to ensure that the pinning has completed between updates, then sometimes the `Operation is invalid after previous operation` is thrown.

Is there a more robust way of doing array operations?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create an array of items with Parse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25920977/create-an-array-of-items-with-parse)

Comment: I do not think it is a duplicate of that question, cause in most cases my implementation is working. It is only sometimes that the exception is thrown. Usually at `removeAll` it seems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the Parse [documentation under arrays](https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#objects-arrays) it says

"Note that it is not currently possible to atomically add and remove items from an array in the same save. You will have to call save in between every different kind of array operation."

When you both add and remove from your parse object, it will throw the error "Operation is invalid after previous operation". To avoid this error first add the new values to the array, save the object, remove the old values, then save again.

Comment: Thank you that is correct. Been a while since I posted the question, but am pretty sure that I was aware of that as well at the time. Thus I believe I saved between each operation. But with no other answers and since I have refactored the code since to avoid the issue, I accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, the value for an array on the dashboard reads `(undefined)`. If you manually change it to `(null)` and try to add to it. It will throw this error.