# Why can't I add an object to the array in Parse?

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to add an object to an array in Parse, but I keep on getting this error. How do I fix it?

```
 func loved(sender: UIButton){
    let object: PFObject = PFUser.currentUser()!
    object.addObject(playertitle.text!, forKey: "LikedSongsTitle")
    object.addObject(playerartist.text!, forKey: "LikedSongsArtist")

    object.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if(error != nil){
            print(error)
        }else{

            print("saved")
        }
    })

}
```

[image]

Comment: Try `addUniqueObject` instead of addObject

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: Have you previously removed an object from one of the arrays without saving? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28586218/array-operations-sometimes-throws-operation-is-invalid-after-previous-operation If you set an exception breakpoint, which line is throwing the exception?

Comment: No I have not this is how the columns look like. The ones with [] are the ones I am trying to add the objects to. http://puu.sh/m45ij/9e52490b48.png

Comment: It's the first object.addobject line @Paulw11

Comment: Btw, you should include more of your stacktrace

Comment: For what its worth, this isn't a particularly good way to structure your data.  You should have a separate class `LikedSongs` with a pointer back to the user and columns for `songTitle` and `songArtist` (Or a pointer to your `Songs` class if you have one) and then you can just add a new row to the liked songs class rather than trying to maintain two related arrays

Comment: I agree with @Paulw11. This would definitely help simplify your code.